# Migration to Survey Creator V2 over React

Tags: migration, updates, surveyjs

I am working on Migration to Survey Creator V2 on reactJs 16 I followed all the migration steps which are documented but getting  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isCreatorDisposed')
at SurveyCreatorComponent.renderElement (SurveyCreator.tsx:61:1)

I didnt understands that which part I have missed to achieve the smooth migration of survey JS creator